# AR Modeling: Why residual is white noise?

Tags: autoregressive-model, lpc, linear-prediction

I was going through AR modeling.

The AR model of  a covariance stationary process can be expressed as:

$$x[n]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p} \alpha_i x[n-i] + \epsilon[n]$$

where $p$ is the model order and $\epsilon[n]$ is the residual

1) Why is it that the residual $\epsilon[n]$ is a white noise? Is it by definition or can it be shown to be a white noise?

2) Where is the assumption on the stationarity of $x[n]$ used? In other words, if $x[n]$ is not stationary, what would have changed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a hand-wavy argument, but the idea is to derive the coefficients $\alpha_i$ so that the norm of the error $\Big\||\epsilon[n]|^2\Big\|$ is minimized.  we assume that $x[n]$ is a stationary *"random"* process, we know all of the previous samples $x[n-i]$ and we want to make a good guess at $x[n]$ with a linear combination of the previous samples.  we can only make **some** guess of the next $x[n]$ if it is not a white random process.  if it **is** white, knowing the previous samples is not going to help us at all.  if it is **not** white, then the autocorrelation of $x[n]$ is not zero for non-zero lags and from that we can compute $\alpha_i$.

now if $\epsilon[n]$ was **not** white, we could do further LPC to make a good guess at $\epsilon[n]$ and make a better guess for $x[n]$, but if the coefficients $\epsilon[n]$ are **optimal**, then we can't make a better guess for $x[n]$.  so then the error of our guess for $x[n]$ and what we really get has to be white.

Comment: in practice, assuming white noise, is the same as assuming normality of the error term in the discrete case. The error term can be assumed to  have some other distribution  but it should have a mean zero or else the expectation won't be zero. Keeo in mind that minimizing residuals in non-normal case does not maximize likelihood function. it does in the normal case. So, in non-normal case, it's better to maximize likelihood directly, rather than minmize norm of error.  Error term can be assumed to be MA(q) also but then it's not an AR model anymore.

Comment: yeah, i probably shoulda said that the DC component of $\epsilon[n]$ must be zero.  otherwise, any DC component can be absorbed intl $x[n]$.  it's a similar reason to why any non-white component of $\epsilon[n]$ must be zero.